# Android - How to align editText and submit button bottom?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I read some articles and some tutorials about layout but I didn't get yet how it works... I have the following code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:hint="Type your message" ></EditText>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Send"></Button>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"
    android:id="@+id/webview" ></WebView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to align my editText and send button on bottom and my webview above.. any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: use relative layout or nested linear layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </WebView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Type your message" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Send" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: +1 and correct answer because that was the only that really works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: By the way, just one question, the editText and the button have 50% of width, there is a possibility to change it? set the button as 10% of width? Thank you!

Comment: Add to EditText android:layout_weight="0.9" and to Button android:layout_weight="0.1" in the linear layout

Comment: @Lara Glad it helped you. Yeah, you can make button as 10% of width, you just need to play with `weight` attribute. The answer given by Sebastian works perfect. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4):

There are many ways to make it work:

1. Linear Layout

   - Display the elements in the order you added them

     ```
       <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="vertical">

       <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webview"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight=".5"></WebView>

      <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">

      <EditText
           android:id="@+id/edit_text"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:hint="Type your message"></EditText>

       <Button
          android:id="@+id/button"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="Send"></Button>

       </LinearLayout>


     </LinearLayout>
     ```

     [image]
2. Relative Layout

   - Display elements in relative to other components

     ```
      <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

      <WebView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="400dip"
          android:id="@+id/webview" ></WebView>

     <EditText
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
          android:id="@+id/edit_text"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:hint="Type your message" ></EditText>

     <Button
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/button"
          android:layout_centerInParent="true"
          android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/edit_text"
          android:layout_below="@+id/webview"
          android:text="Send"></Button>


     </RelativeLayout>
     ```

     [image]

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't careful when I read you requirement, I modified the code and images for other users :) Glad you could found your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight=".9" >
</WebView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:hint="Type your message" >
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Send" >
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/webview" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:hint="Type your message" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:text="Send"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This could also be achieved with a RelativeLayout as root and without the second LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

Use relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:hint="Type your message"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">//align in parent bottom
</EditText>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:text="Send"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/edit_text"> //align to the roght of the EditText
</Button>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/webview" ></WebView>
</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: wrong answer please correct before you get downvoted.

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: relative layout does not contain orientation.

Comment: @DanSnow `weight` attribute is only for `LinearLayout`. So better change it soon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try nesting a linear layout in a relative layout as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type your message" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Send" >
        </Button>
    </LinearLayout>

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/container"  >
    </WebView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

If you need the EditText and Button in one line, you would have to use orientation: horizontal for LinearLayout.

Comment: @Aniruddha I have mentioned: > "If you need the EditText and Button in one line, you would have to use orientation: horizontal for LinearLayout." in answer. **Plus** OP didn't mention that he wants the EditText and Button in same line.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with nested LinearLayouts, or you can change your root LinearLayout to RelativeLayout. With RelativeLayout, you would add attributes on your WebView, EditText, and Button that specify how each element should be aligned relative to the other elements. See the [Relative Layout Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html).